# Ransack Rails - One parameter in Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm a total beginner in Rails and I try to use Ransack to filter results.
I have a model called 'adventures' which has many parameters, of which 'main_activity'. I try to implement a form in my homepage, where you can type the kind of activities you are looking for (later I will implement a dropdown so it will be limited to existing activities).

Here is what I have in my pages_controller:

```
def search
                  if params[:search].present? && params[:search].strip != ""
                     session[:bourse_aventuriers_search] = params[:search]
                  end

                  arrResult = Array.new

                  if session[:bourse_aventuriers_search] && session[:bourse_aventuriers_search] != ""

                     @adventures_main_activity = Adventure.where(active: true).all
                  else
                     @adventures_main_activity = Adventure.where(active: true).all
                  end

                  @search = @adventures_main_activity.ransack(params[:q])
                  @adventures = @search.result

                  @arrAdventures = @adventures.to_a

               end
```

And in my home.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Quelle activité ?",
            class:"form-control" %>
        </div>
```

For the moment, whatever I type in the form, I get all the 'adventures' in the data base ; I find it logical because I did not change the 1st `@adventures_main_activity = Adventure.where(active: true).all`. 
I don't know how to change it so that It will give me only the adventures whose main_activity is the keyword that I type in the form. Can anyone help me ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a lot of surplus code in your search.  Your controller should only need the @q parameter as follows:

```
@q = Adventure.ransack(params[:q])
@adventures = @q.result
```

The @adventures will then return any matches as an active record.

If you pass no parameters then the query will return all records (same as doing an Adventure.all).

When you submit the form the ransack search will pass a "q" param which will contain all the form items.  Your's may look something like this:

```
"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"search_cont"=>"rock climbing"}, "commit"=>"Search", "controller"=>"adventures", "action"=>"index"
```

If you use a debugger you can see this information by typing "params" in the command line.  It will also appear in the server output.

Using an example of one I did in my application here is the exact code I used:

View:

```
  <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <%= f.label :email_cont, "Email:" %>
      <%= f.search_field :email_cont, :placeholder => "Please enter and email to search for", :class => "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <%= f.submit 'Search', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Reset', users_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

Controller

```
  def index
    @q = User.ransack(params[:q])
    @users = @q.result(distinct: true).order(:email).page params[:page]
  end
```

The classes are just Bootstrap CSS which you won't need if you are not using bootstrap.

EDIT

The search_form_for @q has to exactly that and the @q has to be set in the params for it to work.  Ransack is very specific about them.  So your @search in

@search = @adventures_main_activity.ransack(params[:q])

should be @q.  In your view change your form_tag to search_form_for and it should work.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks a lot, I think I understand but what should I change and where in my entire search method ? I hardly guess what to change... Thank you :)

Comment: I would put the code in the index.  You can include the search as a form on the page then show the results with a table.  I can extend the view code I used in my example if that's useful.

Comment: Mark, Thank you very much, that's really helpful. I understand better the mechanism. I'll try it your way right away !